# build BottomSheet from an method flutter

Tags: flutter

have this method witch return bottom Sheet, I want to pass String and double variable as an argument but when I do this an error appears in the invoking statement.

here is the code of my method :

```
Widget buildShowModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context) => Container(
       
          child: Column(
            children: [
                          SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: 350,
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (newGlucose) {
                    glu = newGlucose;
                    glucose = double.parse(glu);
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      MyFlutterApp.glucose_meter,
                      color: nave,
                      size: 35,
                    ),
                    filled: true,
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: nave,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: nave,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                    labelText: ("نسبة السكر في الدم"),
                    labelStyle: textStyleGP,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 25),
              Buttons(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 150,
                  text: "اضافة",
                  onPressed: () {
                    addValues(glucose, glucoseValus);
                  }),
            ],
```

),
),
);
and here is the invoking statement:

```
Buttons(
  onPressed: () {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: buildShowModalBottomSheet
    );
  },
  text: "إضافة قياس سكر الدم",
),
```

And this is the error :

```
Error: The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)'.
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').context: context, builder: buildShowModalBottomSheet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very easy I created a class  that return the method I want and the argument I added them as a property